# Есть ли способ в PyQt5 плавно менять цвет кнопки, когда мышка зависает над ней/ как это делается в с++?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpushbutton

Есть ли способ в *PyQt5* плавно менять цвет кнопки, когда мышка зависает над ней?

Я видел в интернете примеры с *с++*, на *питоне* нашел только изменение как анимацию, то есть она запускается в цикле.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qpropertyanimation/

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, 
        QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
import sys


class MyLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)

    def _set_color(self, col):

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.foregroundRole(), col)
        self.setPalette(palette)

    color = pyqtProperty(QColor, fset=_set_color)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):     

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button)

        hbox.addSpacing(40)

        self.label = MyLabel("Summer")
        font = self.label.font()
        font.setPointSize(35)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"color")
        self.anim.setDuration(2500)
        self.anim.setLoopCount(2)
        self.anim.setStartValue(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QColor(255, 255, 255))

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.anim.start)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 380, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Color anim')
        self.show()    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(60, 60)

        self.color1 = QtGui.QColor(240, 53, 218)
        self.color2 = QtGui.QColor(61, 217, 245)

        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            valueChanged=self._animate,
            startValue=0.00001,
            endValue=0.9999,
            duration=250
        )

    def _animate(self, value):
        qss = """
            font: 75 10pt "Microsoft YaHei UI";
            font-weight: bold;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius:21px;
        """
        grad = "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 {color1}, stop:{value} {color2}, stop: 1.0 {color1});".format(
            color1=self.color1.name(), color2=self.color2.name(), value=value
        )
        qss += grad
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)

    for i in range(5):
        button = Button()
        button.setText("Button {}".format(i))
        lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addStretch()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]